# Excel Addin is not showing up

Tags: excel, vba

if i protect my macro in Excel add-in  by password then i can't add it to a "New tab" through customize ribbon option

Is there any option where can i add it to a customize ribbon as i don't want to send it unprotected

Answer (score 0):

You can password protect the code module in the VBE editor. Whether this solution works for you depends on the type of add-in ofcourse.

> VBE>Project Explorer>WBAProject (right click)>VBA Project
>   Properties>Protection>Lock Project for Viewing and set Password